# Flutter : AppLifecycleState not work if devices in locked screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I use **AppLifeycleState** to detect Behaviour my app when the user using it. For detect my app not being used, i used

- **AppLifecycleState.paused**
- **AppLifecycleState.inActive**
- **AppLifecycleState.detached**

Because i want detect if my App not being used for 1 second, i throw user to Confirmation Fingerprint (Like Whatsapp). Everything is fine i can detect if my app not being used if user press recent app, Home button and throw user to Confirmation Fingerprint if user comeback again.

But the problem is , When devices screen in locked up then it opened again , user not throwing to Confirmation Fingerprint.

I surely can see in console my app is **AppLifecycleState.paused** and **AppLifecycleState.inActive**, but strangely if I hot reload <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>s</kbd> in my IDE my app throwing me to Confirmation Fingerprint.

Why can be like this ?

## Working 1

[image: Applifecycle Work 1]

## Working 2

[image: Applifeycle Work 2]

## Not Working !

[image]

> Already tested too in real Device (Redmi Note 4) , and still not working.

## Source Code AppLifecycleState

```
@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    setState(() => _appLifecycleState = state);
    if (widget.userBox == null) {
      print('Box User Null');
      return;
    } else {
      if (widget.userModelHive.fingerPrint || widget.userModelHive.pinCode) {
        if (_appLifecycleState != AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
          //? Berarti Lifecylenya InActive , Paused , Detached , Maka Simpan Waktu Keluarnya
          final actionBox = await repository.changeDateExit(
            userModelHive: UserModelHive()
              ..id = widget.userModelHive.id
              ..giverName = widget.userModelHive.giverName
              ..pinCode = widget.userModelHive.pinCode
              ..fingerPrint = widget.userModelHive.fingerPrint
              ..darkMode = widget.userModelHive.darkMode
              ..tokenExpiry = true
              ..durationToken = widget.userModelHive.durationToken
              ..dateExit = DateTime.now()
                  .add(Duration(seconds: widget.userModelHive.durationToken)),
          );
          print(state);
          return actionBox;
        } else {
          print('Resumed Lifecycle');
        }
      }
    }
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
  }
```